# How to read the interrupt flag in x86 processor

Tags: c++, c, assembly, interrupt, flags

Are there any assembly instructions to let us directly read the interrupt flag in processor Flags register in Assembly?

Is it possible to read the Interrupt Flag in C/C++ ?

Comment: It is not important, I need the instruction for both

Comment: Why? Are you writing a kernel module?

Comment: @user2485710 What do you mean by 'where do you specify that'?

Comment: @EJP `asm` instructions for 32 or 64 bit are different, I think that this is obvious .

Comment: I need to understand that an interrupt happened during running a code, and I want to do that by checking the Interrupt flag

Comment: But checking the interrupt flag won't tell you that. That's not [what it means](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt_flag).

Comment: @EJP : How I can do that !?

Comment: I doubt if you can. Interrupts happen all the time. Why do you think you need to know?

Comment: @user2485710 You answered the question I deleted and didn't answer the question I preserved. It really isn't so much trouble to answer the question for both, 32 and 64 bits, and 16 bits too, if you know the answer, rather than just ask endless questions.

Comment: @EJP I want to check [Control Flow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow) of a program, and I need to know it

Comment: @Javad, I think you're barking up the wrong tree.  The mere fact of an interrupt does not affect the logical flow of your program.  Some side-effect of the interrupt may be visible to your program, e.g. user pressed a key, but the interrupt is long gone by the time your program will notice.

Comment: The thing is, as other commenters have suggested, if you need to ask this question at all, you do not understand enough of interrupt system to make use of such information.  Those who do know enough already know the answer.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLAGS_register_%28computing%29) you use the PUSHF, PUSHFD, or PUSHFQ instructions, according to which architecture you're on.

Unless you're writing a kernel module I don't see the point. It will never be clear in user mode.

Answer (score 1):

You need a bit of inline assembly.  For example, Linux does this in 'irqflags.h'.  This function works for both 32-bit and 64-bit IA.

```
static inline unsigned long native_save_fl(void)
{
    unsigned long flags;

     /*
      * "=rm" is safe here, because "pop" adjusts the stack before
      * it evaluates its effective address -- this is part of the
      * documented behavior of the "pop" instruction.
      */
     asm volatile("# __raw_save_flags\n\t"
              "pushf ; pop %0"
              : "=rm" (flags)
              : /* no input */
              : "memory");

     return flags;
}
```

This returns all the processor EFLAGS bits, including the interrupt enable (EFLAGS.IF) on bit 9.  If you'd like a check just for IF, mask the return value by 0x200.

Comment: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/x86/include/asm/irqflags.h#L20

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're writing your own operating system or some type of embedded like program. Instead of reading the processor interrupt flag, you should have your interrupt routine set or increment some location in memory, or to push back messages to some type of message queue so that the interrupt routine can trigger a thread or allow some main level routine to check if the interrupt routine has processed an interrupt.